# Why does "step" change?

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool

I have a RRD created by this command

===

```
data_sources = [ 'DS:Pprod:GAUGE:10:0:6000',     
             'DS:Pcons:GAUGE:10:0:6000', 
             'DS:Pdiff:GAUGE:10:-6000:6000'  
           ]

rrdtool.create ( rrd_filename,
                 '--step', '5',                      # one sample every 5 sec
                 '--start', 'now - 7d',
                 data_sources,
                 'RRA:MAX:0.5:1:6307200')            # we keep 1 year
```

===

I am filling it properly -

===

```
    <!-- 2022-05-19 12:25:45 CEST / 1652955945 --> <row><v>4.291018731e+03</v><v>1.715717220e+03</v><v>2.574301511e+03</v></row>
    <!-- 2022-05-19 12:25:50 CEST / 1652955950 --> <row><v>4.286880929e+03</v><v>1.721000000e+03</v><v>2.564880929e+03</v></row>
    <!-- 2022-05-19 12:25:55 CEST / 1652955955 --> <row><v>4.286880929e+03</v><v>1.721000000e+03</v><v>2.564880929e+03</v></row>
```

===

Now I want to "xport" some data from it :

```
rrdtool xport -s $epochStart  -e $epochEnd  --step 5 --json  -t   DEF:pot=$ifn:Pprod:MAX XPORT:pot
```

===

And in the output JSON I find the "step" has changed :

```
{ "about": "RRDtool graph JSON output",
  "meta": {
    "start": 1652738755,
    "end": 1652824970,
    "step": 215,
    "legend": [
      ""
          ]
     },
  "data": [
    [ "1652738755",0.000000000e+00 ],
    [ "1652738970",0.000000000e+00 ],
```

===

Any logical reason for that ?

PD.- "rrdtool info" says

```
pi@R4:~/python/pkw/dades $ rrdtool info ./pkw.rrd 
filename = "./pkw.rrd"
rrd_version = "0003"
step = 5
```

Comment: Seems strange; which version of rrdtool are you using? can you do an `rrdtool info` on the $ifn file that you are using `rrdtool xport` on, to confirm it has the expected 5s step?

Comment: pi@R4:~ $ rrdtool --versio -> RRDtool 1.7.1

Comment: data of "info" command appended to main body, at bottom

Comment: OK so I've duplicated this, and it looks like a bug caused by out-of-range data.  I'll put the info below

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by trying to export data outside of the current rage for the defined RRA.

Your RRD has only a single RRA defined, from (now-7d) until (6307200x5sec) in the future.

The data you show as being added to the RRD are for times around epoch=1652955945; but the export you are trying is for times around epoch=1652738755, before the RRA starts.

When I tried to duplicate this, I created an RRD:

```
rrdtool create $RRD --step 5 --start 1652955935 \
  'DS:Pprod:GAUGE:10:0:6000' 'DS:Pcons:GAUGE:10:0:6000' \
  'DS:Pdiff:GAUGE:10:-6000:6000' 'RRA:MAX:0.5:1:6307200'
```

Then added data to it

```
rrdtool update $RRD \
  1652955940:0:10:20 \
  1652955945:100:200:300 \
  1652955950:400:500:600 \
  1652955955:700:800:900 \
  1652955960:1000:1100:1200
```

If I try to extract the data from within the range of the defined RRA, then it works:

```
rrdtool xport -s 1652955945 -e 1652956000 --step 5 --json \
  -t DEF:pot=${RRD}:Pprod:MAX XPORT:pot

{ "about": "RRDtool graph JSON output",
  "meta": {
    "start": 1652955950,
    "end": 1652956000,
    "step": 5,
    ...
```

However, if I try to extract from a range that is not within the available data space, RRDTool fails to pick a meaningful RRA and so appears to default to a 215s step.

```
rrdtool xport -s 1652738755 -e 1652824970 --step 5 --json \
   -t DEF:pot=${RRD}:Pprod:MAX XPORT:pot

{ "about": "RRDtool graph JSON output",
  "meta": {
    "start": 1652738970,
    "end": 1652824970,
    "step": 215,
    ...
```

I don't know why RRDTool is defaulting to this step size; however, it is documented behaviour that RRDTool, when doing a graph or xport, will attempt to find the best-fit RRA to cover the *entire* requested data range at the requested consolodation, even if this means changing the step size.  So, this looks as if RRDTool has given up on finding a workable RRA and has given you a default of 215s step with empty data.